# partition and format local ssd in start script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to set up a "scratch" local SSD on  Google Cloud Platform / Google Compute Engine in a start script for a preemptable instance to be run on VM creation. No valuable data is on the VM when this script is run.

After creating a VM with a local SSD from `gcloud` or the web console, there is some setup to do on the VM.

[Local SSD Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd) says I should:

1. identify the ssd block device with `lsblk`
2. format it with `mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/[block-dev-from-part1]`
3. mount it somewhere && enjoy

But in step 2 I get an error that `/dev/sdb1` is not found.

`fdisk` reveals that `/dev/sdb` exists but has no partition table.

I could use fdisk manually and that works, but how can I partition the SSD and setup in a start script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to take a chance that the SSD is always at /dev/sdb
and that fdisk doesn't change their user interface, you can simply run fdisk and supply fdisk's input in an `EOF` block as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
fdisk /dev/sdb <<EOF
n
p
1


w
EOF
mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sdb1
mkdir /tmp/ssd
mount /dev/sdb1 /tmp/ssd
chmod 777 /tmp/ssd
```

The fdisk input is `n` for new, `p` for system partition, then `1` for partition 1, two blank lines to accept the defaults from fdisk, then `w` to write the partition table.

Answer (score 1):

The local SSD can be used directly as a block device without partitioning.

You can: `mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sdb`